# What do you call the ability to tell good from bad?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

It is the ability to tell good people from bad people just by observing them. It is like being a good judge of character, a connoisseur of human nature. I would like to find a single word that succinctly captures this characteristic.

For example, there is a fictional character called *Daryl Dixon* in *The Walking Dead* who is said to have the ability to tell good from bad. Here is a more detailed explanation for you to get a better idea (spoilers ahead so I used the spoiler tag):

> In the TV series version, in  Season 5, Rick and his group arrives to a safe zone called *Alexandria* which is a walled-off community. They are invited to this place by someone who is called Aaron. He is a recruiter of this community who tries to find people outside that can be helpful to the community. (with the help of his partner Eric who was injured in one episode). One night, Aaron reveals that he wants Daryl to be Alexandria's recruiter because he doesn't want to risk Eric's life anymore and Daryl can tell the difference between a good person and a bad person.<sup>2</sup>

Interestingly, it is also said that our ability to tell good from bad is universal and unlearned. It is [based on a study](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/3315395/Babies-can-tell-friend-from-foe.html)<sup>1</sup> where it is found out that babies as young as six months old are able to tell friend from foe. But this should apply to only basic distinction as an instinct to survive. The context I provided suggests being experienced also.

The words that came to my mind were ***discerning*** and ***sagacious*** but they are about showing good judgement and having a keen insight in general. I think there might be a more precise term for this.

---

<sub>1 [telegraph.co.uk](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/3315395/Babies-can-tell-friend-from-foe.html)</sub>

<sub>2 [walkingdead.wikia.com](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Daryl_Dixon_%28TV_Series%29)</sub>

Comment: Probably *have the sixth sense:  - grasping the inner nature of things intuitively.

Comment: Charismatic Christians have "discernment of spirits" as one of their Gifts of the Spirit, so the word _discernment_ does have some form here.

Comment: It's presumed we intrinsically know the difference between bad and good, but I don't believe that. We take for granted that *good* and *evil* are easily identifiable, but the real question is, what is “good”? Define what is “evil”? (You tell the difference between [*good and evil*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_and_evil), or [*right and wrong*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics) less so with "good and bad")

Comment: I agree with Mari-Lou - that baby study merely showed that babies can tell the difference between agents who act helpfully and agents who act unhelpfully, based on obvious observable behaviour. In real (adult) life, there is no black and white distinction between "good people" and "bad people", and there is no such thing as a magic ability to tell the difference; and there is no single word for such a precise magical ability either I'm afraid.

Comment: The expression I was looking for was "social convention" It's society that tells us what is "good" and what is "bad". You get punished for doing "bad" things, hence we equate *badness* with *evilness*. This question belongs on philosophy IMHO .

Comment: Basically you're talking about "being a good judge of character", and it's a complex and unreliable characteristic.  Too often such judgments are made based on outward appearances, and even folks with a good intuitive sense are often hoodwinked by psychopaths -- people without any "moral compass" who are experts at pretending to be who they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think showing good judgement is exactly what you're describing in "telling good people from bad people", so I would use *discernment* as the quality.

If you're looking for a more scientific bent, you could use *discriminating*, which can still be used to mean "exhibiting good selection abilities" even though its alternate meaning of "showing bias" is beginning to take over.  It's rarely used when talking about selecting people, for the obvious reason that it can much more easily be confused with its negative alternate meaning.

If you're looking for a more supernatural connotation, you could use *perceptive*, which has a bit of "unknown origin of the ability" connotation to it due to its use in "extra-sensory perception".  *Perceptive*, however, doesn't limit itself to "telling good people/things from bad" but rather implies an ability to discern hidden depths or meanings regardless of their quality.

Answer (score 1):

You could try **perceptive**, which is the ability to perceive; in this case the ability to perceive the quality of the person being scrutinized.

Answer (score 0):

Even ***a Cassandra*** does that, by telling you the evil in advance.

But perhaps you prefer ***a Mother Theresa***, who emphasizes the good.

Comment: Interesting approach but I want a word that defines the ability, not an allusion. (not my downvote).

Answer (score 0):

Since [humanism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/humanism) can be :

> An ethical system that centers on humans and their values, needs, interests, abilities, dignity and freedom; especially used for a secular one which rejects theistic religion and superstition.

Why not a **be humanist**?

---

From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praxeology) :

> **praxeology**
>
> > The study of human action or conduct.

Comment: This is a scientific approach. Thanks for the word but it doesn't refer to the ability. There is the term *praxeologist* also who studies *praxeology*. It looks like *praxeology* is used in the development of economic theories and the term was often used by the Austrian economist Ludwig von Mises.

Comment: @ermanen It's all I find about it for the moment. Still searching...

Comment: @ermanen edited

Answer (score 0):

What about-

**[moral](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moral) judgments**

of or relating to principles of right and wrong in behavior :  **ethical** <**moral**/ethical judgments>

([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moral))

Answer (score 0):

A noun for this quality is **discernment.**

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned "discerning" in the question. The word I'm looking for is like a specific type of discernment.